# Nodejs 6.2 self executed script arguments

Tags: node.js

I can't pass the arguments to my `test.js` script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(process.execArgv)
```

When I run `test.js a1 a2 a3` in terminal, I got `[]` result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

For your example code, it shows the following:

```
$ ./test.js a1 a2 a3
[ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/private/tmp/test.js', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$ node --a1 test.js
```

This will results :

```js
['--a1']
```

For more Information refer : [process.execArgv](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execargv)

Comment: Thanks @Jitendra Khatri, I'm new to Nodejs so I missed the document. Insteed of using `process.execArgv`, use `process.argv` must be the correct.